# Datetimepicker shows up in a 'naked' way

Tags: yii, outlook, datetimepicker

I want to set up both date and time in a custom field (Yii).
For this i've chosen this [datetimepicker](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/datetimepicker/).
But as i've loaded it into protected/extentions it now works, but its outlook is somehow 'naked'. I've rounded datepicker's appearence in red. [image: the datetimepicker outlook in view]

Its configuraition is:

```
 <?php $form->widget ('ext.CJuiDateTimePicker.CJuiDateTimePicker',  
            array (
                'attribute'=>'start',
                'model'=>$model,
                'value' => $model->start,
        'language' => 'en',
                'options'=>array (
                   // 'timeFormat'=>strtolower(Yii::app()->locale->timeFormat),
                    'showSecond'=>true,

                ),  
            )   
        ); ?>
```

How to fix it? Am i missing some skin files? How to get them?
I use bootstrap theme FYI.

Comment: Show :
                        'themeUrl' => Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl,
                        'scriptUrl' => Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl."/jquery-ui",

Comment: didn't help, it's shifted the appearence down, yet remained 'naked'. the `'scriptURL'= ...` expression had no effect.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your page with Firebug or something to see if any javascript/css files aren't correctly loaded? It's usually something like that.

Comment: yes, i've inspected with a web sniffer. But i've found no such related issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in the Yii app development i was using the [NlsClientScript Yii Extention](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nlsclientscript/) for preventing duplicate scripts loading. So, the *datatimepicker's css file* has not been loaded into the current nlsXXXXXXX.css file. It turned that this NlsClientScript *does* manage/aggregate the css files load, the docs saying opposite though...

> From documentation:
>    The extension **does not prevent the multiple loading of CSS files**.

So I've found the corresponding file, deleted it and reloaded the app.

> From documentation: 
>   The extension doesn't watch wether a js/css file has been changed. If you set the merge functionality and some file changed, **you need to delete the cached merged file manually**, otherwise you'll get the old merged one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a styling issue .
Download correct Style.css file it will show datepicker correctly .